# How to draw concentric hexagons?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need to draw concentric hexagons (4 to 10 in each set) randomly using Python turtle graphics (see image). I can draw random hexagons but can not make concentric ones:

```
import turtle
from random import randint

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("yellow")
brad= turtle.Turtle()
brad.color("blue")
window.colormode(255)

def drawPoly(sideLen, noOfsides):
    for i in range(noOfsides):
        brad.forward(sideLen)
        brad.left(360/noOfsides)

for i in range(20):
   sideLen = randint(20,150)
   xpos = randint(-200,200)
   ypos = randint(-200,200)
   brad.pensize(randint(1,3))
   brad.pencolor(randint(1,255),randint(1,255),randint(1,255)) 
   brad.penup()
   brad.setpos(xpos,ypos)
   brad.pendown()
   drawPoly(sideLen,6)


window.exitonclick()
```

Here's a link to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfoWA.png)

How can I make hexagons within a hexagon for 4 to 10 times and then move to the next hexagon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies to development as well as posting here.  Start with a simple function or block of code that makes concentric hexagons without worrying about color, thickness, or style of the lines.

The key thing about hexagons is that the 'radius' (center to corners) is the same as the edge length (corner to corner).  (Concentric pentagons, for instance, are harder, requiring some trig.)  Assume you want two corners on the x axis.  If the center is x,y, start at x+e,y at a rotation of 120 (where 0 is facing right).  Given `x`, `y`, a list `edges` of radii-edge lengths, and turtle `t` in a pen-up state, the following should work.

```
for edge in edges:
    t.setpos(x+e, y)
    t.setheading(120)
    t.pendown()
    for i in range(6):
        t.forward(e)
        t.left(60)
    t.penup()
```

EDIT: replace setangle with setheading, thanks to comment by cdlane.

Comment: The function you want is `setheading()`